# What does a2enmod proxy_fcgi setenvif do?

Tags: command-line, apache2, php, php-fpm

My coworker and I recently spent a long amount of time trying to figure out why PHP 7 was showing as plain text in the browser rather than running. We found an upvoted StackOverflow answer that contained these commands.

```
sudo a2enmod proxy_fcgi setenvif
sudo a2enconf php7.0-fpm
sudo service apache2 restart
```

It fixed the problem, but unfortunately the answer did not include an explanation on what these commands do. We understand `sudo service apache2 restart` but not the first two lines. I searched online, but only found more instances of this code without a real explanation on how it works or why it was needed.

**What do these commands do and when is it needed?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, `a2enmod` is a script that enables the specified module within the apache2 configuration.

The module `proxy_fcgi` provides support for the FastCGI protocol. The associated `setenvif` sets the variables sent to the FastCGI.

The `a2enconf` script enables the specified configuration file within apache2, in this case `php7.0-fpm` (which I assume configures PHP 7.0 - I've not played with this one).

Hope that helps.